# Why does this shell pipeline exit?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe

I have a shell pipeline for generating 10 characters password at random:

```
cat /dev/urandom | base64 | head -c 10
```

My question is `cat /dev/urandom | base64` is an infinite output stream which will not exit by itself. But why does appending `head -c 10` make the whole pipeline exit? I assume `cat`, `base64` and `head` are 3 separated processes, how can `head` make the `cat` process exit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After `base64` outputs 10 bytes, `head` gets enough inputs and exits. When the former attempts to output more bytes, it will receive [SIGPIPE signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE) and hence exits too。For the same reason, `cat` will exit in turn.

Answer (score 24):

`head` closes the input file after reading the required amount. when a pipe is closed from one side, the other side gets write errors; this causes `base64` to close, which in turn causes `cat` to close.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the only reason `head` gets any input at all is that `base64` writes output after it gets a certain amount of input, i.e. when its buffer is full. If it were to read until EOF, it would be reading forever, and `head` would never get a crack at any of it. So a similar pipeline, like `cat /dev/urandom | sum | head -c 10` would behave differently, since `sum` waits for EOF.

Comment: Rob's comment is *extremely* relevant.  If the process inherits a SIGPIPE handler or ignores SIGPIPE (eg if it is run under older python interpreters subprocess module) and does not check write errors, it will not terminate.  There is a *huge* difference between a write error and receiving a SIGPIPE, and programs that ignore both issues are prone to running indefinitely.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: A process cannot inherit a SIGPIPE handler.  It can inherit the SIG_IGN non-handler, but any signal handler is reset to the default when a process uses `exec()` to replace itself.  It's not hard to see why: the pointer to a function in the old process is almost certainly not a good choice for the new process.  But you're right that a process that ignores write errors and is also ignoring SIGPIPE will continue working far too long.

Answer (score 4):

Piping works by connection the output of one process A to the input of B. The connection can be broken, when

- A closes its output. B will get EOF.
- B closes its input. A will get an error that the output is no longer available when it tries to write the next byte.

Since these two cases are so common, the handling has been moved into the C standard lib.

Comment: Thanks, but what does "the handling has been moved into the C standard lib" mean? is A and B terminated by shell instead of they detects the closing of input/output and stop themselves?

Comment: When B closes its side of the pipe, A will receive a signal. The code in the I/O routines of the standard library c.lib (`fprintf()`, `open()`, `read()`, ...) handle the signal and the function call will return return the errno EPIPE = "Broken pipe".

Comment: @AaronDigulla, I disagree. I am not aware of any C library that installs a SIGPIPE handler, nor do my experiments suggest it. In fact, SIGPIPE is delivered which causes any program that hasn't installed a handler (that is, 99% of all programs) to exit.

Comment: correct, Rob, it's SIGPIPE. thanks! could you create an answer? i will accept it. currently, the 2 answers are not perfectly correct.

Comment: @Robᵩ: What I mean is that you don't see "Broken Pipe" error in the console, so someone must handle this signal.