# What is the policy of terminating piped program in bash?

Tags: bash, pipe, termination, sigpipe

When is the piped program terminated and who controls this termination process? I've read [Bash: why the pipe is terminated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031344/bash-why-the-pipe-is-terminated) but it covers this question only partially. After trying to answer this question myself I made a couple of examples to see their outputs. And this one I don't understand: (`a.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

echoerr() { echo $@ 1>&2; }

echoerr a.sh started

sleep 1
echo 1

sleep 1
echo 2

sleep 1
echo 3

sleep 1 # Line 1
echo 4  # Line 2

echoerr a.sh finished
```

And I run it as `./a.sh | head -3`. The output is:

```
a.sh started
1
2
3
```

From the output I understood that `./a.sh` was terminated with `SIGPIPE` signal after reading first 3 lines of input because no more data was needed. But when I remove *either* Line 1 *either* Line 2 the output changes to the following:

```
a.sh started
1
2
3
a.sh finished
```

So my question are:

- What is the policy of terminating piped program?
- Why does Line 1 affect program behaviour?
- Why does Line 2 affect program behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've said, you shell script will die if it attempts to write to a closed pipe. It won't if it doesn't.

If you remove the second line, `a.sh` doesn't attempt to write to its `stdout` after `echo 3`, so it has no reason to fail.

Removing the first line might not get you the same result every time you run your test. There's a timing issue. If the last two `echo` statements are processed before `head` attempts to read from it's input (and terminate because it's reached 3 lines), then `a.sh` won't get a broken pipe error. If the timing is such that `head` does a read in between the two `echo`s, then `a.sh` will get the pipe error, and die.