# Why is this pipe not terminated

Tags: linux, unix, find, pipe, unix-head

Topic [Why is this pipe terminated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10031344/2910279) explains, why a pipe may prematurely be closed by 'head':

```
find / | head
```

So why is the following pipe not closed by 'head'?

```
find / -exec zgrep -l 'a' {} \; | head
```

using grep instead of zgrep produces lots of

```
find: "grep" terminated by signal 13
```

warnings, but the the pipe nevertheless stays active. Is there any way to prematurly stop 'find' in combination with 'grep'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen because find is spawning many grep process, but since it's not find wich output to the pipe, it don't get the signal